# Is it possible to run a ASP.NET web project created in VS2015 on VSCode OSX?

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-code, dnx

Thank you for the help in advance.

I'm used to developing asp.net web projects in visual studio for windows. With the new asp.net open source, I'm trying to develop on my mac. I already set my development environment and run the boilerplate. My question now is, can I import a  traditional project developed in vs and in some way adapt to run and continue developing in Vscode and dmx?

Comment: Don't you need IIS and SqlServer to run it?

Comment: Should be fine as long the VS2015 project is built on ASP.NET 5 and CoreCLR. Project solution would obviously not work and you would need to define build tasks and launch configuration.

Comment: @DaneBalia ASP.Net 5 hasn't been called that for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... So long as it's based on .Net Core.

.Net Framework 4.5, 4.7 etc is most definitely not cross platform and requires Windows and, more often than not, IIS to run.

So I suppose the real answer is, it depends.